# CSS image background?

Tags: css, image, background, styles

I need help with my image background. If you go to my website, www.tripwirehosting.com : You'll see that there is a gray void next to black and gray tiles. (The gray void will appear on widescreens only)I would like to replace that gray void with said black and gray tiles that are on the top and bottom of the "Features", how would I do so?

Comment: you can't. That image isn't a background, but an image with some elements that can't be used as bg

Comment: I understand that's an image, I would like to replace it though.

Comment: you need to create a new image with that pattern and simply use `body{background:#333 url(your_image.png)}` . COlor is not exact, just referencing a dark grey

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, would make that a background-image, cut the image along the outermost lines (remove the gradient) and use `background-repeat: repeat-x;`

Comment: Just added this and no luck at all. It doesn't show anything, just the same gray background. NOTE: I added this to my HTML file, do I need to add it to my CSS file instead?      <style>
   background {
    background-image: url("img_headerback.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}  
</style>

Comment: I messed with it some more, and came to 2 solutions, both which involve editing features.png :/ (unless you have them as separate layers in a photoshop file you'll have to tweak them). The gradient fade is built into the feature.png, so it looked funny when I added it

1) You can either fill in the center of the features frame with your bg color (the center is transparent and the background bleeds through), or 2) edit the frame out so that you have featureframe.png, and headerback.png (that way would could just have headerback repeat. The 1st option is preferable!

No simple code workaround :/

Comment: Yeah, I could do that...However, what would the required code be to add the background? @CSS Apprentice

Comment: Sorry, I've been out of town. I just did backround-image: url(""); and background-repeat: repeat; when I was messing around with it